# How to perform this delete operation on a DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have the following problem

I have 2 table on a database respectivelly named **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** and **VulnerabilityReference** that are bind togheter by another table named **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** that contains only 2 fields: the Id of the first table (**VulnerabilityAlertDocument**) and the id of the second table (**VulnerabilityReference**)

Now if I try to delete a record from **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** SQL server say to me that I can't do it because exist a referential Integrity constraint.

So if I want delete a record from **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** I have to do the following operations:

- I have to select the rows in **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference** where the first field is the Id of the record that I want delete from the **VulnerabilityReference**
- I have to delete the corresponding record from **VulnerabilityReference**
- Finaly I have to delete these row from **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference**

I think that this could be a correct solution but I have some problem to understand how can I store the result of the selection in **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference**

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the order of operations wrong.  All you need to do is:

1. Delete all rows from VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference where VulnerabilityReferenceID FK is equal to the target id that you want to delete.
2. Delete VulnerabilityReference where ID is equal to the target id that you want to delete.

The way you have it, you'll have the same issue again.  You cannot delete VulnerabilityReference until you have deleted related records in VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference.

Comment: If you read close it appears the ID to delete is the ID of VulnerabilityAlertDocument (not VulnerabilityReference)

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a cascade delete to your foreign key. This would handle the delete of related child rows automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference] 
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT 
[FK_VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference] 
FOREIGN KEY([VulnerabilityReferenceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[VulnerabilityAlertDocument] ([VulnerabilityReferenceID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing references

VulnerabilityAlertDocument
VulnerabilityReference

VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference
This has FK to the other two tables

If you want to delete a row from VulnerabilityAlertDocument then you must first delete any rows that reference it from VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference

That is two easy operations

```
delete VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference where docID = x   
delete VulnerabilityAlertDocument where docID = x
```

Mixing in VulnerabilityReference is different
You cannot simply get the refID where docID = x and delete those from VulnerabilityReference
Other docID may have that same refID
For that you would need something like this

```
delete toDelete
  from VulnerabilityReference as toDelete
  join VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference 
    on toDelete.refID = VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference.refID 
   and VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference.docID = x  
  left join VulnerabilityReference as toKeep 
    on toKeep.refID = VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference.refID 
   and VulnerabilityAlertDocument_VulnerabilityReference.docID <> x 
 where toKeep.refID is null
```